# How to set AWS region for bellatrix automation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation

I'm trying to automate AWS EC2 instance creation by using '[bellatrix](http://bellatrix.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#)'.
One problem is setting of AWS region (e.g. us-west-2) with this tool. There is no description about region from the tool's document page.

Any idea?

Comment: OK. I found out that bellatrix do not care region and just use default region (maybe us-west-1). I'm trying to modify bellatrix source codes. I'll update if I finish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick solution.
From the `ec2_lib.py` source codes of bellatrix, make change as like the below:

```
import boto.ec2

def getEC2Connection(self):
    # Use your region as 1st argument
    return boto.ec2.connect_to_region("us-west-2", aws_access_key_id=self._key, aws_secret_access_key=self._sec)
```